# How to remove class "show" from previous li in angular?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript

I have a question, how to remove class "show" from previous li when the user clicks another menu in angular?

I've tried using the directive, but the "show" class still can't be removed from the previous li. This is the directive I have made :

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener, Renderer2 } from "@angular/core";

@Directive({
  selector: '[appDropdown]'
})

export class DropdownDirective {
  manageDropdown : boolean = false;

  constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer2)   {}

  @HostListener('click') openDropdown() {
    if(!this.manageDropdown) {
      this.renderer.addClass(this.elementRef.nativeElement,'show');
      this.manageDropdown = !this.manageDropdown;
    } else {
      this.renderer.removeClass(this.elementRef.nativeElement, 'show');
      this.manageDropdown = !this.manageDropdown;
    }
  }
}
```

And here's the appDropdown selector that I call and use in the HTML file

```
<ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item dropdown" appDropdown></li>
    <li class="nav-item dropdown" appDropdown></li>
    <li class="nav-item dropdown" appDropdown></li>
    <li class="nav-item dropdown" appDropdown></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You need to move appDropdown selector to the <ul> as using that you can remove child <li> show class.

Comment: @Dipten after i move, what should i do in directive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the parentElement.childNodes to get the list of all childNode of the parent of the currently clicked element.

Add the below to your openDropdown Hostlistener.

```
for(let child of this.elementRef.nativeElement.parentElement.childNodes){
      this.renderer.removeClass(child, 'show');
 }
```

Final Code:

```
@HostListener('click') openDropdown() {
    for(let child of this.elementRef.nativeElement.parentElement.childNodes){
      this.renderer.removeClass(child, 'show');
    }
    
    if(!this.manageDropdown) {
      this.renderer.addClass(this.elementRef.nativeElement,'show');
      this.manageDropdown = !this.manageDropdown;
    } else {
      this.renderer.removeClass(this.elementRef.nativeElement, 'show');
      this.manageDropdown = !this.manageDropdown;
    }
  }
```

Comment: woaahhhhh... totally its work, thank you

Answer (score 0):

I would probably move the responsibility of opening/closing the dropdowns one level higher. Meaning the component that renders the `navbar` would know the currently open menu, since as I understand you only want to have one open at a time.

Another solution would be to process the arguments of click `HostListener`, and compare the `target` to your current `nav-item` element. If its different,  you can remove the class.

Comment: if I move the appDropdown selector to 1 level higher above it, in this case I move it to the <ul> tag. what should I change in the directive?